# Book which covers these contents of the same level of Fulton's book.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, book-recommendation

My question is very specific. I'm studying Chapter 8 of [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and I would like to find another book (or online sources) which covers these contents: Divisors, the Vector Spaces $L(D)$ and Derivations and Differentials. I'm looking for beginner's books of the same level and language of Fulton's book but with more detailed explanations, examples and so on. I'm talking about specifically of these contents. I find Fulton's book very concise.

I really need help, if anyone could help me, I would be very very grateful!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The theory is about the same in the complex analytic case, and in fact that setting is the original motivation, so it's helpful to study it there.  I like (with *some* reservations) Rick Miranda's book "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces" for this.

Comment: The problem is the language of Miranda's book is completely different than Fulton's one.

Comment: If you understand the basic idea first then any differences in language (which I think are actually fairly minor) won't be a problem.  If you don't understand the basic idea first, I don't think any amount of comparing the formal proofs in different books is going to matter.